# "Add-In Warning. The license information for this add-in is missing or expired, so it may have limited functionality"

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-store

One of our customers is facing an issue while trying to activate an app created by them.

The app is published as free of charge.

Location: https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104379484&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false

It is downloaded a number of times by different users and works fine. However, for one particular user an error message is being displayed in Excel Online when trying to install and use the app:

"Add-In Warning. The license information for this add-in is missing or expired, so it may have limited functionality"

I went through the following documentation:

https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/add-in-license-schema

However, I am not sure if the issue is related to app publishing/licensing in Office store as the issue is specific to one single user. I am yet to setup a call with the end user and troubleshoot the problem. Before I proceed, I wanted to check if you have ever come across this error.

Any leads will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Best Regards
Saptarshi

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this issue? I'm assuming if it's just one user that they must have a specific version of Excel, or had at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated, and in my case the user receiving the error received this error for every add in they attempted to install, indicating this was an error with Microsoft Word and not the add in.

The interesting thing was when using the web link "Open In Word" for the add-in, Word would prompt with a trust warning and open Word with the add-in installed, and the add-in would load. Closing and reopening Word after this though resulted in the same license error, so the entire process had to be repeated every time.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: No, everything points to a client side issue, and reinstalling Word on the customer's machine may have resolved the issue, but I honestly can't remember. It is what i recommended though. @dwillis77